# Trying to Update Model Through Directive But Cannot Add Class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update both what the user sees and what is contained within my $scope.project variable within a directive, but am having serious problems.  At first, I was able to update the view, but the model would not get updated. Now, I can update the model, but the view will not get updated.

If I try to call `scope.$apply();` after changing the model, I get an error that the digest/apply was already running and I get double the output from what I normally would see in the ng-repeat, but the class actually gets added to the view (only on the duplicated part) and changes its color.  If this isn't clear I can upload a screenshot.

Here's the directive:

```
.directive('colorByChange', function(){
    return {
        scope: {test: '=passedValue', parent: '=parent', i: '=i'},
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.ready(function(){
                    if (scope.test == undefined){
                        return;
                    }
                    var change;
                    if (scope.test.changed) {
                        change = scope.test.changed;
                        scope.parent[scope.i] = scope.test.val;
                        if (change) {
                            switch (change) {
                                case 'ADDED':
                                    element.addClass('greenify');
                                    break;
                                case 'DELETED':
                                    element.addClass('redify');
                                    break;
                                case 'UPDATED':
                                    element.addClass('bluify');
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    element.addClass('NotWORKING');
                            }
                        }
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<td>
  <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" color-by-change passed-value="keyword" parent="brand.keywords" i="$index">
    <span ng-hide="keyword.changed">{{keyword}} </span>
    <span ng-show="keyword.changed">{{keyword.val}} </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

Here's the html that's generated:

```
<td><!-- ngRepeat: keyword in brand.keywords -->
  <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" color-by-change="" passed-value="keyword" parent="brand.keywords" i="$index" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><span ng-hide="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false">aa </span><span ng-show="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"> </span></span><!-- end ngRepeat: keyword in brand.keywords -->
  <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" color-by-change="" passed-value="keyword" parent="brand.keywords" i="$index" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <span ng-hide="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false">hey </span>
  <span ng-show="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"> </span></span><!-- end ngRepeat: keyword in brand.keywords -->
  <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" color-by-change="" passed-value="keyword" parent="brand.keywords" i="$index" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><span ng-hide="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false">aa </span><span ng-show="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"> </span></span><!-- end ngRepeat: keyword in brand.keywords -->
  <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" color-by-change="" passed-value="keyword" parent="brand.keywords" i="$index" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope greenify"><span ng-hide="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding ng-hide" aria-hidden="true">{"val":"hey","changed":"ADDED"} </span>
  <span ng-show="keyword.changed" class="ng-binding" aria-hidden="false"> hey</span></span><!-- end ngRepeat: keyword in brand.keywords --></td>
```

Comment: dont use `$.apply()`, use the `$watch` on the variable on which you want to change the views.

Comment: So if i use $watch on the variable, angular will see the change and update everything automatically?  I don't see why that fixes the issue.

Comment: kinda of `$watch(variableIamInterseted, function(){ //do the stuff according to changes and those would be reflected  }`.  Just go through AngulrJS  $watch documentation once, you would get the idea.

Comment: But, the stuff I am interested in is adding a class to an element and updating the value in my model.  I need to take an object, add a class depending on the parameters, then convert that object into a string from its value parameter.  So the color of the element needs to change in the view and underlying value needs to change in the value.  I still don't see how $watch would help there.

Comment: If you could please create a jsFiddle.

Comment: Try wrapping your code with [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `element.ready(function(){}` - It should ensure executing the code after the current `ngRepeat` digest loop is finished

Comment: @Alon Okay I will try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-class` instead of directive:

```
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="keyword in brand.keywords" ng-class="{'greenify': keyword.changed == 'ADDED', 'redify': keyword.changed == 'DELETED', 'bluify': keyword.changed == 'UPDATED', 'NotWORKING': keyword.changed != 'DELETED' && keyword.changed != 'ADDED' && keyword.changed != 'UPDATED'}">
        <span ng-hide="keyword.changed">{{keyword}} </span>
        <span ng-show="keyword.changed">{{keyword.val}} </span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I change the underlying value from an object to a string when it has the .`changed` property, so wouldn't it lose the class?

Comment: @DaveM - I think not, because the `ngClass` expression is checking the value from the object and not the string.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see what you're saying, the issue is that I would like to actually change the model so that `keyword === {changed: 'Update', val: 'I am a keyword'}`, gets changed to `keyword === 'I am a keyword'`.

Comment: I see. So you do need the directive, but I think that because you're changing the model, it will affect the `ngRepeat` loop. Maybe you should try [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression): `ng-repeat="keyword in ::brand.keywords"` to prevent updating the view by your directive

Comment: Brilliant!  That was the perfect solution - thank you.  I added the $timeout method, one-way binding, and the ng-class idea, and now it works!  I never need to update the page I'm on (from user input), so this works!  I think this would still be giving me headaches if I was stuck w/ two-way binding.

Comment: If you update your answer I'll certainly give you credit, maybe providing a little insight into why you think my original code wouldn't work would be helpful.

Comment: @DaveM - I'm happy I was able to help, and I'll update my answer later

Comment: Thanks again.  That `::` is a really helpful addition to angular I didn't know about before.